# Open an .rdl file in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: azure, rdl

I installed Visual Studio 2019, SSDT, and Reporting Services. I'm using Azure DevOps to store my .rdl files and project files.

In Visual Studio, I can see the project with the .rdl files and the lock next to them indicating that they are source controlled using Git, but I can't open any of the .rdls. When I click Open in Visual Studio, I get an html file, and when I click Open With, nothing related to Reporting Services is available as a selection. Any idea how I can open the .rdl files using the Report Designer? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. In Visual Studio, create a New Project (Ctrl + Shift + N)
2. Select Report Server Project. For the solution: create a new solution. Click Create.
3. In the Solution Explorer panel, you will see folders under your new solution which are Shared Data Sources, Shared Datasets, and Reports. Right click on Reports > Add > Existing Item…
4. Browse for your RDL file.
5. In the Solution Explorer panel, now under Reports you can see the RDL you just uploaded. Double click and it should open the Designer view by default.